# which filter for encoding a png interlaced using windows imaging components (wic) with the c# wrapper?

Tags: c#, wic

I'm trying to encode an image as an interlaced png using WIC. I can save the image as png without any problems and set the interlaced mode. But if i try to set a filtermode (any filter), i get the following error:

```
[System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException] = {"The bitmap property type is unexpected.   (Exception from HRESULT: 0x88982F8E)"}
```

Do i set the value of the property bag in a wrong way? This is the code, the exception is thrown at propBag.Write.

```
[...]
var arg = new IPropertyBag2[1];
encoder.CreateNewFrame(out outputFrame, arg);
var propBag = arg[0];
var propertyBagOptions = new PROPBAG2[2];

propertyBagOptions[0].pstrName = "InterlaceOption";
propertyBagOptions[1].pstrName = "FilterOption";
propBag.Write(2, propertyBagOption1, new object[] { true, WICPngFilterOption.WICPngFilterAdaptive});
[...]
```

Thanks for Help,
Stephanie

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe this is because the [`FilterOption` property needs to be an Unsigned Byte](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/gg430028(v=vs.85).aspx):

```
| Property Name |VARTYPE|Value Range       | Default Value          | 
|---------------|-------|------------------|------------------------|
|InterlaceOption|VT_BOOL|TRUE/FALSE        |FALSE                   |
|FilterOption   |VT_UI1 |WICPngFilterOption|WICPngFilterUnspecified |
```

The underlying `Write` method is marked to marshall the `Value` as a `VARIANT` (i.e. `UnmanagedType.Struct`), which is correct:

```
void Write(
   uint cProperties, 
   [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPArray)] PROPBAG2[] pPropBag, 
   [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Struct)] ref object pvarValue
);
```

I'm not going to test it; because i can't, but i think the fix is to cast your PNG filter option to the C# equivalent of an *unsigned byte* byte.

```
propBag.Write(
   1, 
   propertyBagOption, 
   UInt8(WICPngFilterOption.WICPngFilterAdaptive));
```

The reason i think this is because from my native code, i was giving the property value as a variant. But the variant was actually a signed 32-bit (aka `Int32`). This caused the error:

```
0x88982F8E
```

When you look at `WinCodec.h` (which is the native code that .NET imaging is using), it corresponds to error:

```
  WINCODEC_ERR_PROPERTYUNEXPECTEDTYPE = HRESULT($88982f8E);
```

I has to make sure to *force* the variant to contain a VT_UI1:

```
propertyBagHelper.Write('FilterOption', VarAsType(WICPngFilterAdaptive, VT_UI1));
```

Then it succeeded.

This is all great from native code, when you know what's going on. The .NET/CLR/C# wrapper world loves to obfuscate everything; so you don't really know what the parameters contain when you pass them.

> **Note**: Any code released into public domain. No attribution required.